# Simple awk command issue (FS, OFS related)

Tags: linux, awk

I tried to reorganize the format of a file containing:

```
>Humanl|chr16:86430087-86430726 | element 1 | positive
>Humanl|chr16:85620095-85621736 | element 2 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:80423343-80424652 | element 3 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:80372593-80373755 | element 4 | positive
>Humanl|chr16:79969907-79971297 | element 5 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:79949950-79951518 | element 6 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:79026563-79028162 | element 7 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:78933253-78934686 | element 9 | negative
>Humanl|chr16:78832182-78833595 | element 10 | negative
```

My command is:

```
awk '{FS="|";OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

Here is the output:

```
>Human|chr16:86430087-86430726  |      element 1      |
>Human  chr16:85620095-85621736         element 2      negative
>Human  chr16:80423343-80424652         element 3      negative
>Human  chr16:80372593-80373755         element 4      positive
>Human  chr16:79969907-79971297         element 5      negative
>Human  chr16:79949950-79951518         element 6      negative
>Human  chr16:79026563-79028162         element 7      negative
>Human  chr16:78933253-78934686         element 9      negative
>Human  chr16:78832182-78833595         element 10     negative
```

Every line works fine except for the first line. I don't understand why this happened.

Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: You already have the answer, but consider for future questions including sample input, current and expected output as text.

Comment: OK, will do hat in the future.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Short answer

`FS` and `OFS` are set too late to affect the first line, use something like this instead:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' FS='|' OFS='\t'
```

You can also use this shorter version:

```
awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='\t' '$1=$1'
```

#### A bit longer answer

It doesn't work because awk has already performed record/field splitting at the time when `FS` and `OFS` are set. You can force a re-splitting by setting `$0` to `$0`, e.g.:

```
awk '{FS="|";OFS="\t";$0=$0} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

The conventional ways to do this are 1. set `FS` and others in the `BEGIN` clause, 2. set them through the `-v VAR=VALUE` notation, or 3. append them after the script as `VAR=VALUE`. My preferred style is the last alternative:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' FS='|' OFS='\t'
```

Note that there is a significant difference between when `-v` and post-script variables are set. `-v` will set variables before the `BEGIN` clause whilst post-script setting of variables are set just after the `BEGIN` clause.

Comment: What are "post-script variables" in the last paragraph of your answer? This term is not expained before. Do you mean the `VAR=VALUE` combo you specify after your script?

Comment: @jena: yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 21):

try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

Comment: I myself was looking for the other answer (the format of `-v OFS='\t'` specifically), but I think this is a better way to fix the issue OP was having.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to this but you can also just use the `tr` command: `tr "|" "\t"`